# Determining if a function is onto or one-to-one?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Hi I want to show whether the below function is onto or one-to-one or neither, but I'm a bit stuck.

For one-to-one I think it's enough to show that if I have the integers 2, 4, -2, -4 I end up with the same f(a, b), thus it's not one to one.

I am slightly more confused when it comes to the onto proof, any ideas?

f: Z x Z -> Z given by f(a, b) = |a| - |b|

Comment: To show it's onto, show that every element of the codomain has an element of the domain that is mapped to it. Fix some z in the codomain. Can you identify a pair (a,b) in the domain such that f(a,b)=|a|-|b|=z?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof for the function not being one-to-one has the right idea, but your function takes pairs of integers, not integers.  You should say that $f(2,4)=f(-2,-4)$

To show it is onto, you just want to show that if you are given an integer $k$ you can find an ordered pair $(a,b)$ such that $f(a,b)=k$.  You don't have to have the same rule for every $k$.  It is easier here if you split it depending on the sign of $k$.  If $k \ge 0$ can you find an ordered pair?  If $k \lt 0$?